# Yammer OAauth: Getting 403 for external networks, can I create a Global Access app using a Free/Basic Yammer account?

Tags: c#, oauth, yammer

I have a website (say website1.com) that wants to let users login via their own corporate Yammer accounts. I signed up for Yammer (Basic/Free) account using my adminuser@website1.com email address. Then created an App and setup the whole OAuth server side workflow.

Now say a user with email address someone@website2.com wants to login to my site using Yammer. They have their own Yammer accounts using the website2.com domain.

Things work perfectly when any user with [xyz]@website1.com email address tries to login.

For other (external Yammer users) things work till the point of getting to the Linking page in OAuth workflow. After user says "Allow" (linking of their Website2.com network) with my App. Yammer redirects to back to website1.com with authorization_code. The next step as per documentation is to do a POST and retrieve the access_token. This request is failing with the following error.

> Forbidden (403): Failed to retrieve access token. HttpStatusCode: Forbidden, Your network is not allowed to request an OAuth token for this Application

Initial web search indicates I have to Deploy my app and request for Global Access approval. I have done that but not received any response yet (only been 24 hours).

However Yammer's [API documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/multi-network-testing) states I can create an external network and invite external users into my network to test external network access.

So I created an external network using website1.com's Yammer account, and invited someone@website2.com to my network. However, the user still can't login to Yammer on website1.com. Gets the same 403 error.

I am now worried that free/Basic Yammer networks cannot create Global Access apps and my request to Approve App will go unanswered. So the question to the community is: Has anyone managed to create a Global Access app on Yammer that allows external networks to be used for OAuth, using a free/Basic Yammer account recently (after MS bought Yammer and rolled it into O365)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to get this sorted with help from the Yammer team. To answer my questions:
1. Yes, free Yammer accounts can request for Global Access.
2. Submit your App through Yammer after putting in all mandatory data.
3. Yammer team with get back with request for further details. Respond to them nicely. (Be prepared for some security related question about your own site/app).
4. In about 5-7 working days, your app will get listed for Global Access and the Yammer team member will inform you once it is done.
5. If you request for Public Directory Listing (where your App is featured along with other apps) there are additional steps that we haven't done yet.